# Menu strip save option in vb

Tags: vb.net, save

I made a menu strip and and I need to know how to make the option I have to save actually save.

I use `Me.Close` for the close option I just need to know how to save.

Thank!

---

From Comments

this is what I have...the save obviously is wrong though.

```
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click 
    SaveToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems("Save").Enabled = False 
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you saving? Where are you saving too?

Comment: Saving to a text file. It is going to be a listbox with book names in it in the form.

Comment: What is your code so far?  Do you know how to use the StreamWriter object?

Comment: this is what I have...the save obviously is wrong though. 
  
    `Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click

        SaveToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems("Save").Enabled = False
    End Sub`

Answer (score 4):

```
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("book_list.txt", True)
        For Each line As String In ListBox1.Items
            writer.WriteLine(line)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Assuming your `ListBox` is called `ListBox1`

Comment: I wrote it in and nothing happened. I had to also include Imports System.IO

Comment: Can you post everything that you have so far?

Comment: sure: `Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("book list.txt", True)
            For Each line As String In lstBooks.Items
                writer.WriteLine(line)
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub

Comment: I really don't see what's wrong with that. All it's supposed to do is write out to a file line by line, the items in your ListBox. If the file doesn't exist, the program will create one in the working directory called "book list.txt". Does anyone else  have any insight?